# Python pandas adding precision using lambda

Tags: python, lambda, precision, series

I am trying to find the precision of a data field using the following code

```
fieldStructure.loc[fieldName,'Precision'] = df[fieldName].apply(lambda x: len(str.split(str(x), ".")[1])).max()
```

however it returns a huge number (18). upon investigating I see the following behaviour. I understand it is due to the way floating points are stored. however is there a way I can get to desired output, without losing precision of my source data?

My dataframe is as below.

```
print('Sample Data: ',df[fieldName])

Sample Data:  0     0.0111
1     0.0109
2     0.0097
3     0.0113
4     0.0088
5     0.0101
6     0.0108
7     0.0113
8     0.0119
9     0.0090
10    0.0069
11    0.0585
12    0.0031
13    0.0205
14    0.0066
15    0.0081
16    0.0016
17    0.0122
18    0.0088
19    0.0132
20    0.0051
21    0.0032
22    0.0104
23    0.0097
24    0.0137
25    0.0142
26    0.0087
27    0.0106
```

However when I try to print the same using lambda i get the following results

```
df[fieldName].apply(lambda x: print(x))
Name: MyColumn, dtype: float64
0.0111
0.0109
0.0097
0.0113
0.0088
0.0101
0.0108
0.0113
0.0119
0.009000000000000001
0.0069
0.0585
0.0031
0.0205
0.0066
0.0081
0.0016
0.0122
0.0088
0.0132
0.0051
0.0032
0.0104
0.0097
0.0137
0.0142
0.0087
0.0106
```

I tried to replicate the behaviour using shell, but here it seems to work as expected.

```
>>> df = pd.Series([0.0111,0.0109,0.0097,0.0113,0.0088,0.0101,0.0108,0.0113,0.0119,0.0090])
>>> df.apply(lambda x: print(x))
0.0111
0.0109
0.0097
0.0113
0.0088
0.0101
0.0108
0.0113
0.0119
0.009
0    None
1    None
2    None
3    None
4    None
5    None
6    None
7    None
8    None
9    None
dtype: object
```

How to get rid of the extra precision in  df[fieldName].apply(lambda x: print(x)) (0.009000000000000001 from 0.0090)?

Comment: From where do you get your original data set? Is that through some mathetmatical manipulation? There is an explanation  to the current behavior, but to be able to make it clearer I would want to know the source of your data.

Comment: @johanl this is being read from a text file. CSV file. The same issue happens with 2 other float columns in the same file. There is a fourth float column that doesn't seem to have this issue.

Comment: OK, and the content of the CSV file is `0.0090`? That's a bit strange, because that should typically be represented as a number ever so slightly smaller than `0.0090` since that is the closest value that can be represented. I haven't looked at `pd.read_csv()` but I find it hard to believe that it should do ssomething strange like this. And the source file says 0.0090?

Comment: Yes, the source file reads 0.0090.

Comment: That's odd. That is not behavior I see when reading data from disk. However, I can replicate the behavior after some mathematical operations.

Comment: The only operations I do on the data is replace nulls with '0's. in this case the column does not have any nulls. when trying to check the precision I was converting to a string, but I stopped doing that while debugging. There maybe something with the encoding of the file. as this logic works on most other files. I'll investigate that.

Answer (score 0):

The issue happens randomly when trying to do any row based iterations over the dataset. I was able to get the same behaviour by using .iterrows() as well.

However when I used float_precision= 'high' as a parameter for read_csv the I would see a much more expected behaviour when using lambda or iterrows.

```
df = pd.read_fwf(currentFile, parse_dates=False, skiprows=HeaderPos, skipfooter=0,  widths=width, header=forceHeader, float_precision= 'high')
```